# Silverlight 5 app from iframe not closing in IE9

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer, iframe, dojo

I am developing a web application using Dojo v1.8 and my target machine runs IE9 and Silverlight 5.1.20125.  In this web app, the user can select a tool from a toolbar at the top of the page that will open up in a content pane (or an IFrame if it is an external tool) below the toolbar (only one tool can run at a time).

The bug I am encountering is that one of the external tools that opens in an IFrame runs a Silverlight app, and if the user tries to select another tool, the new tool won't open and the Silverlight application stays there.  After checking the DOM Tree, all references to the Silverlight application have been wiped, and the new tool is there instead (which is the desired behavior).

So my question is, why is the Silverlight Application still being viewed even when it is gone from the DOM Tree, and is there a way to programmatically close it from Javascript?  Also, I do NOT have access to the source code of the Silverlight Application.

Comment: ****UPDATE / CORRECTION****
The Silverlight Application does NOT in fact continue to run.  If I click anywhere where the IFrame used to be (or "is", I'm not quite sure what to call the IFrame's state when it's not in the DOm Tree but still rendering) then the entire page freezes (including the overarching web application).

Answer (score 0):

Well I did not manage to solve this issue directly. However, there was another bug that I ran into which involved the java swing library not working on the production machine. The solution was to add the following tag as the first element of head:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8>
```

This forces IE to use IE8 instead of IE9. This trick solved this other issue, but inadvertently solved this issue as well. Here are several links that helped lead me to the solution (amongst others):
http://sourceforge.net/p/djproject/discussion/671154/thread/d7662f61
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ff959805.aspx#_Compatibility_issues_with_1